# Dynamic href based in GET parameter

Tags: html, parameters, get, parameter-passing, href

I would like to create a link in HTML whose `href` changes based on a GET parameter (example *link*)

As `href` i try this

```
<a href="?url">text</a>
```

but it doesn't work

---

[Here is a gif of how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7TYO.gif)

*Sorry for my English*

Comment: can you be more specific, maybe include some code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're trying to fill out the "href"-attribute of an anchorlink, by dynamically getting an URL from the GET parameter.

This can be done with the help of JavaScript. I found an example [in another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and made it fit your use case. In that same thread you'll find some good examples of other ways to do it as well.

Try out the following snippet:

```html
   <a id="myLink" href="">Text</a>

   <script>
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      const myParam = urlParams.get('link');
      const myLink = document.getElementById('myLink');

      if(myParam) {
         myLink.href = myParam; /* The URL given as a parameter */
      } else {
         myLink.href = '#0'; /* If no parameter, the link leads nowhere */
      }
   </script>
```